# What's the difference between "swollen" and "inflamed"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

As the title says, what is the difference between *swollen* and *inflamed*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words *can* escribe visible changes to the body:

> A part of the body is *swollen* if it's larger than usual. This might be caused by an allergic reaction to, for example, an insect bite.
>
> A part of the body is *inflamed* if it's larger than usual due to an increased blood supply caused by the body's reaction to infection. So *inflamed* areas look redder and feel warmer.

This is the reason for the name: *inflamed* implies more heat.

By analogy the word *swollen* could describe a river carrying a greater flow of water.

Similarly, the word *inflamed* is often used to describe a situation of increased severity.

Comment: Quite so. As [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=swollen+liver%2Cinflamed+liver%2Cswollen+sore%2Cinflamed+sore&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests, you're more likely to have a **swollen liver**, but an **inflamed sore**. As would be expected, given your distinction.

Comment: Not only body parts.  We talk of a **swollen river**.  (But not inflamed.)

Comment: True, I should add that to my answer.

Comment: @GEdgar:  Unless that river is in Hell.  For example, a story could include a passage along the lines of "...as my burning eyes rested upon **the inflamed river of lost souls** before my swollen feet - which was thrashing violently with the immense heat and fire it carries, occasionally splashing me with white-hot droplets of molten lava - despite intense pain, I still managed to exert an involuntary cringe against my red hot chains as I felt yet another burning stoke of the devil's thorny whip cutting deeply across my back..."

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *inflamed* is "became reddened, swollen, hot, and often painful, especially as a reaction to injury or infection."

*Swollen* means " became larger or rounder in size, typically as a result of an accumulation of fluid."